# Where is the Tilde Symbol on Swiss Mac Layout (Home Folder Symbol)?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

Where is the tilde symbol (~) located on a Swiss mac keyboard? Is there a shortcut to easily generate it?

Answer (score 5):

The tilde symbol ~ is used for representing your home folder on your machine. On a Mac keyboard from Switzerland it can be generated with the following shortcut:

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

[image: image of Swiss keyboard]

Comment: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(found it!)